# Let $a,b,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ prove $\{ x = a \pmod m,x=b \pmod n\}$ has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $a,b,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ prove $\{ x = a \pmod m,x=b \pmod n\}$ has a solution  and it is unique modulo $mn$

---

Definitions

$x=a \pmod m \iff m|(x-a) \iff x-a=m q_1$ where $q_1 \in \Bbb N$ 
$x=b \pmod n \iff n|(x-b) \iff x-b=n q_2$ where $q_2 \in \Bbb N$

Also, $\gcd(m,n)=1$ so $\exists  u,v \in \Bbb N$ s.t. $mu+vn=1$

---

*Stuck on Putting it together*

$x=a+m q_1$ and $x=b+nq_2$,

Now $$\begin{aligned} x&=a+m q_1*1=a+m q_1*(um+vn)=a+mmuq_1+vn*mq_1  \\
                      x&=b+nq_2*(1)=b+nq_2(mu+vn)=b+nq_2mu+n^2 v q_2
\end{aligned}$$

***Kind of lost at this point not sure if I took a wrong turn somewhere***

$\vdots$

___=____ $\pmod {mn}$

---

Comment: related to   [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193413/showing-that-x-equiv-a-pmod-m-and-x-equiv-b-pmod-n-ha-s-unique-solution?rq=1) but  with $gcd(m,n)=1$

Comment: Why, this is but a consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @moorish thanks found it on the book :) did not know it was related to  that theorem at the end of the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have $mu+vn=1$, so $mub+vnb=b$ so $$mub\equiv b\pmod{n}$$

Similarly, you hvae $$vna\equiv a\pmod{m}$$

Now just let $$x=mub+vna$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
The map $f\colon \{0,\ldots,nm-1\}\to\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\times \{0,\ldots,m-1\}$, $x\mapsto (x\bmod n,x\bmod m)$is injective and between sets of same cardinality, hence surjetcive.
To see injectivity, assume $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $x\equiv y\pmod n$ and $x\equiv y\pmod m$, hence $x\equiv y\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)}$.